# virt-manager fails to initialize EGL render node for SPICE GL with NVIDIA proprietary drivers

Tags: virtual-machine, graphics-card, virtualization, linux-kvm, virt-manager

I have virt-manager on a Fedora Workstation 26 host.

I have set up a Virtual Machine with Windows 11 Educational.

I have a Spice display server, with Listen Type set to “None”, and OpenGL set on with my NVIDIA graphics card.

I use proprietary NVIDIA drivers.

I also use virtio video with 3D acceleration set on.

However when I start the virtual machine, I get the following error:

```
Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2022-07-08T13:45:11.588270Z qemu-system-x86_64: egl: eglInitialize failed
2022-07-08T13:45:11.588413Z qemu-system-x86_64: Failed to initialize EGL render node for SPICE GL

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 108, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1384, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1353, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2022-07-08T13:45:11.588270Z qemu-system-x86_64: egl: eglInitialize failed
2022-07-08T13:45:11.588413Z qemu-system-x86_64: Failed to initialize EGL render node for SPICE GL
```

How can I have my VM work with 3D acceleration on NVIDIA graphics card?

Answer (score 3):

As stated [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/QEMU/Guest_graphics_acceleration) and [here](https://docs.mesa3d.org/drivers/virgl.html#so-what-can-it-do-now), virtio-gpu works currently only with Linux guests, but in the future it aims to be available for Windows Guests too. However, if you want it to work out of the box, it seems that nouveau driver is better than NVIDIA driver (I can't find the sources for that, but I've read it somewhere during my research on the web, plus I'me currently facing difficulties to achieve that with nvidia driver and I found this post about it [virtion-gpu and NVIDIA drivers](https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/pmqvwf/some_tips_on_using_virtiogpu_and_nvidia_drivers/))
If you want 3D acceleration for Windows guests you have two choices :

1. Use PCI pass-through, but you'll need two graphics card
2. Use vGPU from NVIDIA

You'll find what you need on [arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/QEMU/Guest_graphics_acceleration) for the instructions.